# Javascript: regex with variables to match part of a string containing HTML code

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a regex (containing 1 variable) against a page of HTML code stored as a string.

The HTML string is an array, each element containing something as shown below. (I have split on a certain tag). Each element of the array contains some data of a House (name, amount of square meters, etc). Fictional of course. The point is that I need to match only 1 of these houses by matching the text between the first TD tags, and the part that I need is the VALUE (digits) in the last INPUT tag of the form.

```
<TR BGCOLOR=#D4C0A1>
 <TD WIDTH=40%><NOBR>Luminous&#160;Arc&#160;2</NOBR></TD>
 <TD WIDTH=10%><NOBR>154&#160;sqm</NOBR></TD>
 <TD WIDTH=10%><NOBR>6460&#160;gold</NOBR></TD>
 <TD WIDTH=40%><NOBR>rented</NOBR></TD>
 <TD><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
 <FORM ACTION= METHOD=post><TR><TD>
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=world VALUE=Olympa>
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=town VALUE="Yalahar">
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=state VALUE=>
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=type VALUE=houses>
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=order VALUE=>
  <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=houseid VALUE=37010>
  <INPUT TYPE=image NAME="View" ALT="View" SRC="" BORDER=0 WIDTH=120 HEIGHT=18>
</TD></TR></FORM></TABLE></TD></TR>
```

I constructed the following RegEx:

`var regex = new RegExp(house + "[\\s\\S]+name=houseid value=([0-9]+)>", "i");`

where `house` is the name of the house (in this example, `Luminous&#160;Arc&#160;2`) and the part I need would be the houseid `37010`.

I figured this Regex should work quite fine and give me the hit that I need, however `houses[i].match(regex)` returns null every time. I get no match in the string.

I have tried several approaches so far, including attempting to convert the string to a DOM Object to split up on TR tags (the conversion failed). I feel that I am close, but I am stuck.

Does anyone see why my regex might fail to work?

Kenneth

Comment: **[Don't parse HTML with regexes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)** HTML's too complex for that.

Comment: So how exactly would you suggest  I parse it? This source code is the only string I have, so it figures I somehow need to manipulate it.

Comment: I'll write up a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your regex with Cerbrus's `houses` variable and it works fine.
(I added the lazy quantifier `?` to `[\\s\\S]+`, but it works fine without it as well.)

```
var house = "Luminous&#160;Arc&#160;2";
var regex = new RegExp( house + "[\\s\\S]+?name=houseid value=([0-9]+)>", "i" );

houses.match( regex )[1];    // "37010"
```

Presumably then, your `house` variable has the wrong value or `houses[i]` is not accessing the right string.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the string to your html (in a `display:none` div or something like that), and then just access the DOM like you would anywhere.

For example:

```
<div id="stringContainer"></div>
```

```
var searchstring = "Luminous&#160;Arc&#160;2";
searchstring = searchstring.replace(/&#160;/g, '&nbsp;') // Convert &#160; to &nbsp;

var c = document.getElementById("stringContainer");
c.innerHTML = '<table>'+houses+'</table>';
var h = c.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(var i = 0, l = h.length; i < l; i++){ // Loop through the found elements
    var name = h[i].firstChild.nextSibling.getElementsByTagName('nobr')[0]; // Get the house's name.
    if(name && name.innerHTML == searchstring){ // If the name matches the search string. (innerHTML returns &nbsp; instead of &#160;. hence the replace earlier.)
        console.log(h[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[5].value) // log the value.
    }
}
```

**[Working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rVxYh/)**

Assuming the variable `houses` is:

```
var houses = '<TR BGCOLOR=#D4C0A1>\n\
<TD WIDTH=40%><NOBR>Luminous&#160;Arc&#160;2</NOBR></TD>\n\
<TD WIDTH=10%><NOBR>154&#160;sqm</NOBR></TD>\n\
<TD WIDTH=10%><NOBR>6460&#160;gold</NOBR></TD>\n\
<TD WIDTH=40%><NOBR>rented</NOBR></TD>\n\
<TD>\n\
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>\n\
        <FORM ACTION= METHOD=post>\n\
            <TR>\n\
            <TD>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=world VALUE=Olympa>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=town VALUE="Yalahar">\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=state VALUE=>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=type VALUE=houses>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=order VALUE=>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=houseid VALUE=37010>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=image NAME="View" ALT="View" SRC="" BORDER=0 WIDTH=120 HEIGHT=18>\n\
            </TD>\n\
            </TR>\n\
        </FORM>\n\
    </TABLE>\n\
</TD>\n\
</TR>\n\
<TR BGCOLOR=#D4C0A1>\n\
<TD WIDTH=40%><NOBR>Dark&#160;Arc&#160;2</NOBR></TD>\n\
<TD WIDTH=10%><NOBR>154&#160;sqm</NOBR></TD>\n\
<TD WIDTH=10%><NOBR>6460&#160;gold</NOBR></TD>\n\
<TD WIDTH=40%><NOBR>rented</NOBR></TD>\n\
<TD>\n\
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>\n\
        <FORM ACTION= METHOD=post>\n\
            <TR>\n\
            <TD>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=world VALUE=Olympa>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=town VALUE="Yalahar">\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=state VALUE=>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=type VALUE=houses>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=order VALUE=>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME=houseid VALUE=37010>\n\
            <INPUT TYPE=image NAME="View" ALT="View" SRC="" BORDER=0 WIDTH=120 HEIGHT=18>\n\
            </TD>\n\
            </TR>\n\
        </FORM>\n\
    </TABLE>\n\
</TD>\n\
</TR>';
```